# Why can I specify a late bound lifetime parameter in one case but not the other?

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the following rust program:

```
fn f<'a>(x: &'a i32) {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn main() {
    f::<'static>;
}
```

When compiling it, the following compilation error is outputed:

```
error: cannot specify lifetime arguments explicitly if late bound lifetime parameters are present
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     f::<'static>;
  |         ^^^^^^^
  |
note: the late bound lifetime parameter is introduced here
 --> src/main.rs:1:6
  |
1 | fn f<'a>(x: &'a i32) {
  |      ^^
```

Lets modify the program like this:

```
fn f<'a, 'b>(x: &'a i32) -> &'b i32 {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn main() {
    f::<'static>;
}
```

For some strange reason this compiles now without any compilation errors. Why is this? If the lifetime parameter 'a in the first program was late bound, why shouldn't it also be late bound in the second program? Note that the only change I did between the first and the second program was to add another lifetime parameter and a return type that depends on this new lifetime parameter.

Comment: I will award the first good answer with a bounty.

Comment: The second example isn't exactly out of the weeds, the compiler emits a warning that it won't be accepted in the future.

Comment: @kmdreko: Thanks! That warning explains it! After they make it a hard error the behaviour will be consistent. I missed that warning because I had disabled warnings globally to do a workaround for a problem with using virtualbox shared filesystem. I can give you the bounty if you write that comment as an answer.

Comment: Lifetimes involved in return values are early-bound for some obscure reason that can be probably clarified by folks over at [rust-internals](https://internals.rust-lang.org). I was unable to find / intuitively understand why it is so.